# C#のRegexの正規表現の改行(\r)について

Tags: c#, .net, 正規表現

C#で正規表現で行単位で取得するソースを組んでいたのですが

①`string text ="{\r\n{\r\n";`
②`string text ="{\n{\n";`
③`string text ="{\r{\r";`

```
string[] lineLists2 = Regex.Split(text, "\n|\r\n|\r");
string[] lineLists3 = Regex.Split(text, "(\n|\r\n|\r)");

Regex regex = new Regex(".*[\n|\r\n|\r]");
Match match = regex.Match(text, 0);
```

を行うと、matchには
①`{\r\n`
②`{\n`
となるのですが、③だけ出力値が
③`{\r{\r`
となり、Splitでは`\r`を認識しており、Matchのみが途中の`\r`を認識していないのですが
理由をご存じの方ご教示願えないでしょうか
また、`{\r`にする方法もご存じであれば重ねてご教示お願いします。

環境：Windows10、VS2022 Community

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ピリオド記号 (`.`) は、`\n` (改行文字、`\u000A`) を除く任意の文字と一致](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#any-character-)すると定められているからです。つまり、`.`は`\r`にマッチします。
`".*[\n|\r\n|\r]"`というパターンは`.`が`\r`にマッチしないことを期待した記述ではないでしょうか？
`"[^\r\n]*[\n|\r\n|\r]"`なら期待する結果が得られると思います。

もちろん`Regex.Split`が期待通りの動作をするのは`.`を使っていないからです。

Answer (score 1):

`\r`を認識していないのではなく、Regex.Matchの`.*`が直接の原因です。

正規表現の`.`は任意の一文字を表しますが、[`RegexOptions.Singleline`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#single-line-mode)で単一行モードを指定しない場合は*任意の一文字から\nを除外*します。
つまり`.*`にマッチする範囲は`\n`の手前までなので、①では`{\r`、②では`{`となりますが、③では`{\r{\r`全体となります。
上記の文字列に対して`.*[\r\n]`のような正規表現を使用すると、`*`は[最長一致の量指定子](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions)ですので可能な限り長い文字列を取得しようとします。
その結果、③でマッチする結果は`{\r{\r`となってしまいます。

下記のようにRegex単一行モードとした場合は、①②も末尾までマッチします。
`Regex regex = new Regex(@".*[\r\n]", RegexOptions.Singleline);`

最短一致の量指定子を使用する方法が`{\r`にマッチさせる簡潔な手段です。
`.*`を`.*?`に書き換えることでご質問で意図する出力を得ることができます。

サンプルコード

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var texts = new string[]{ "{\r\n{\r\n", "{\n{\n" , "{\r{\r" };
            foreach(var text in texts)
            {
                // Regex regex = new Regex(@".*[\r\n]");  // うまくいけてないコード
                // Regex regex = new Regex(@".*?[\r\n]", RegexOptions.Singleline);  // 単一行モード
                Regex regex = new Regex(@".*?[\r\n]", RegexOptions.Singleline);     // 単一行モードでも最短一致の量指定子ならばうまくいく
                Match match = regex.Match(text, 0);
                Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```